# How do I connect my Django project to MySql using Windows?

Tags: mysql, django, xampp, sqlclient

I am trying to connect my Django project to the MySQL database but have run into a number of problems. I have tried running the Xampp Control Panel and starting the service there but received this error message...

```
18:55:35  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
18:55:35  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
18:55:39  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
18:55:39  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
18:55:39  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
18:55:39  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:55:39  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:55:39  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:55:39  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
18:55:39  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
19:15:09  [mysql]   Problem detected!
19:15:09  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
19:15:09  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
19:15:09  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
19:15:09  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I have also tried to install mysqlclient through the terminal, however this resulted in the following enormous error...

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c          
'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp    \\pip-install-g0c19c79\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users
\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g0c19c79\\mysqlclient
\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-
er48j2t7'
   cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g0c19c79\mysqlclient\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314
\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,0,1,'final',0) 
-D__version__=2.0.1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" 
-Ic:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users
\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" /TcMySQLdb
/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _mysql.c
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or 
directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools
\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u 
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g0c19c79\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users
\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g0c19c79\\mysqlclient
\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
record-as59yxwj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-
headers 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g0c19c79\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314
\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,0,1,'final',0) 
-D__version__=2.0.1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" 
-Ic:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users
\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" /TcMySQLdb
/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file 
or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools
\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs
\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g0c19c79\\mysqlclient
\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
g0c19c79\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
record-as59yxwj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-
headers 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient' 
Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you add the Database settings you have set in the ```settings.py``` file?

Comment: DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `DATABASE` in your `settings.py`, you need to have `mysqlclient` installed and then `DATABASE` set up properly. Take a look at what that could look like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'someappname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword',
        'HOST': 'yourhost',
        'PORT': 'yourport',        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I have not yet been able to successfully install mysqlclient. The huge error displayed in my original post occurred when I tried to do that

Answer (score 0):

1. Your MySQL server can't be started because of 3306 port is used by another application. So please check 3306 port and kill the process which uses that port before starting MySQL service.
2. Can you please download mysqlclient with .whl format(pre-built version) and install it using pip?

`pip install mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to open the mysql workbench and start a connection using port 3306 so I don't think this is the problem.

I received the following error just now when I tried to install with .whl

WARNING: Requirement 'mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: You need to download it through internet. check this link please. https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.3.12/#files

Comment: Thanks for the link. I received an alert saying windows was unable to open this type of file...

Comment: Please paste that file under your project root and run pip command. That file is not an executable file on windows, so you can't open or run it.

Comment: Yes I did try that. I received this error message:

WARNING: Requirement 'mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Please run pip command where that file is located. Error shows that pip command is not finding the .whl file. Additionally, I send this link to select the correct .whl file so that you can find right one on your python version.http://qpypi.qpython.org/simple/mysqlclient/

Comment: You need to select the correct .whl file on your python version and your os architecture (e.g. 32bit or 64bit) mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl was just a sample.